# Maui Android raises errors when pack it

Tags: c#, maui, .net-8.0

I migrated a MAUI project from NET7 to NET8. I get 2 errors when I try to pack the application to deploy it on the Google Play. The errors are the following:

> error MSB4064: The "AndroidFixManifests" parameter is not supported by the "XamarinDownloadArchives" task loaded from assembly: Xamarin.Build.Download, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null from the path: C:\Users\enric.nuget\packages\xamarin.build.download\0.11.4\buildTransitive\Xamarin.Build.Download.dll. Verify that the parameter exists on the task, the  points to the correct assembly, and it is a settable public instance property.

> error MSB4063: The "XamarinDownloadArchives" task could not be initialized with its input parameters.

I see that the `Xamarin.Build.Download.targets` contains

```
<Target Name="_XamarinBuildDownloadCore"
        Condition="'@(XamarinBuildDownload)'!=''">

    <XamarinDownloadArchives
        AllowUnsecureUrls="$(XamarinBuildDownloadAllowUnsecure)"
        Archives="@(XamarinBuildDownload)"
        DestinationBase="$(XamarinBuildDownloadDir)"
        CacheDirectory="$(XamarinBuildDownloadDir)"
        User7ZipPath="$(XamarinBuildDownloadUser7ZipPath)"
        VsInstallRoot="$(VsInstallRoot)"
        IsAndroid="$(_XamarinBuildDownloadIsAndroid)"
        AndroidFixManifests="$(_XamarinBuildDownloadAndroidFixManifests)"
        />
</Target>
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: See Breaking Changes : https://github.com/dotnet/maui/releases

Comment: I can't find anything related to this issue

Comment: I can't find anything related to this issue. With the NET8 preview, I could pack the application for Android.

Comment: This looks like a Xamarin issue. Did you use the Xamarin NuGet package in the Maui project?

Comment: Yes, As Microsoft recommends, I added `Xamarin.GoogleUserMessagingPlatform`.

Comment: Make sure the resource is correct : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/android/deployment/publish-google-play?view=net-maui-8.0#ensure-correct-package-format and then do a clean build

Comment: Yes, I have this setting

Comment: `Xamarin.GoogleUserMessagingPlatform` this package does not support the .net8.